# Wildfly 10.0:Unable to connect to jconsole from remote host

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jmx

I'm trying to connect to a remote Wildfly (10.0.0) instance using jvisualvm (or jconsole).
I launch the jvisualvm adding jboss-client.jar in its classpath:
jvisualvm --cp:a  /application-server/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin/client/jboss-client.jar
When I try to connect using this connection string:
service:jmx:remoting-jmx://<>:9990

Cannot connect to wildfly-10.0 using service:jmx:remoting-jmx://<>:9990.

I know that the server is listening on 9990 because I was able to open a telnet connection.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,

Laura

Comment: Try with below connection URL      service:jmx:remote+http://10.10.10.10:9990

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried with Jconsole and was able to connect to wildfly app using JMX.
Default Jconsole application cannot connect to wildfly jmx due to missing dependencies .
I followed below steps to resolve this.

1. Go to Java home/bin directory
2. Create a new empty **.bat** file with name jconsole_wildfly__connect.bat
3. Open jconsole_wildfly__connect.bat in any editor
4. write text ->  **`jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=../lib/tools.jar;../lib/jconsole.jar;<wildfly home dir>\bin\client\jboss-cli-client.jar`**
5. save the file and close it.
6. now open the **jconsole_wildfly__connect.bat** by double clicking it.
7. enter the url(service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://:9990) in remote process
8. enter userName and password